# An idiomatic way to check a condition after each await

Tags: javascript, async-await, cancellation

Is there an idiomatic/clean way to check a condition after each await in an async function, then return/throw conditionally?

For example, if we have a simple async function to upload a file to a websocket:

```
// readFileChunks is an async generator that returns 4KB of the file in every yield
async function upload(input) {
    for(const file of input.files) {
        const ws = await openUploadWebsocket(file.name)
        for await(const chunk of readFileChunks(file, 4096)) {
            await ws.write(chunk)
        }
        await ws.close()
    }
}
input.onchange = upload
```

If we want to cancel this operation when user has reselected the files, we probably want to stop the previous run:

```
let previousLock = {stopped: false}
async function upload(input) {
    previousLock.stopped = true
    const lock = {stopped: false}
    previousLock = lock
    
    for(const file of input.files) {
        const ws = await openUploadWebsocket(file.name)
        try {
            if(lock.stopped) return
            for await(const chunk of readFileChunks(file, 4096)) {
                if(lock.stopped) return
                await ws.write(chunk)
                if(lock.stopped) return
            }
        } finally {
            await ws.close()
        }
        alert("Finished uploading")
    }
}
input.onchange = upload
```

Now there is a lot of boilerplate because we have to check this condition after different `await` statements. Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: No, unfortunately there isn't.

Comment: You can have a look at [my fork of the `creed` promise library that supports this kind of cancellation](https://github.com/bergus/creed/blob/cancellation/cancellation.md#coroutines) by implementing it via generator functions, but it doesn't support `for await` yet.